# a:hover doesn't work for nested tag in li

Tags: html, css

This should on hover show small box-menu. For some reason it doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Menu</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />

</head>
<body>

<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="#">one <i>iiiiiii</i></a></li>
<li><a href="#">two <i>iiiiiii</i></a></li>
<li><a href="#">three <i>iiiiiii</i></a></li>
 </ul>

</body>
</html>


ul.menu li{position: relative;} 
ul.menu li a i {display: none;}
ul.menu li a:hover i {display: block; width: 6em; position: absolute; top: 0; 
left: 100%; margin: -1em 0 0 1em; padding: 1em; background: #CDE; 
border: 1px solid grey;}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
left: 100%;
```

is pushing the element beyond the right edge of the browser, so it is not visible. Test by reducing this to 50%.

Answer (score -2):

use this css

you can also use right:0; in `ul.menu li a:hover i` and if you ignore left and right in css the browser will pick it automatically and will align it to the place where it should be without position

```
ul.menu li{position: relative;} 
ul.menu li a i {display: none;}
ul.menu li a:hover i {display: inline; width: 6em; position: absolute; top: 0;right:0; margin: -1em 0 0 1em; padding: 1em; background: #CDE; 
border: 1px solid grey;}
```

Comment: *use this css* - okay, *why*?

Comment: @Hushme, your code is broken, the semicolon after `right: 0` is missing so both `right` and `left` properties don't work. @PeteScott, it's not because `<i>` is set to `block`, it's because `li` with `position: relative` has the full page width, and 100% are counted from it.

Comment: @Hushme If you use `right: 0` you should remove `left: 100%`.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn You're right. I deleted my inaccurate comment.

Comment: i know that but im not writing left:100% or it was not defined in any where in css

Comment: Your answer offers no explanation and also includes invalid css-syntax as pointed out by Ilya.

Comment: I upvoted your answer it works for me even with missing semicolon which is bit weird. Andy stressed where the problem is.

Comment: will you tell me what is invalid css-syntax llya was pointing

Comment: There should be a semi-colon after `right: 0`. Without this to separate the different rules, the rule, and the one following it, are often ignored by the browser.

Comment: i corrected it actuall i got it now that there was a syntax error in my code if we dont define left or right in css it the browser will automatically align the element in my case it was happening too and i thought my code is valid my bad